# BASH syntax error near unexpected token 'done'

Tags: bash, shell-script, for

What is wrong here? I am getting error near `done'.

```
echo " Writing a program to print even numbers by adding 1 if the number is odd."
for i in {1..10}
do
    d=$(($i % 2))
    if [[$d = 1]]
    then
        $iq=$(($i+1))
        echo "$iq"
done
echo "end"
```

Comment: May I recommend that you use [`shellcheck`](https://shellcheck.net), also available as standalone program in many Linux distributions, to check you shell scripts? This would have caught most of the problems you experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
#!/bin/bash -

echo " Writing a program to print even numbers by adding 1 if the number is odd."
for i in {1..10}
do
    d=$(($i % 2))
    if [[ $d -eq 1 ]]
    then
    iq=$(($i+1))
    echo "$iq"
    fi
done
echo "end"
```

Inserted a `fi`, removed the `$` from `$iq=...` and added spaces inside the `[[ ... ]]`.

Comment: it worked. thanks.